# Address of structure "0" for hash linkedlist

Tags: c, hash, linked-list

I encounter a seemly weird way to get node from a linkedlist, and I am confused how it work(it seems ok in most of the time). Is the loop try to scan every node?

So I have a structure A,B,linked_list:

```
structure A{
   struct linked_list *list[HASH_SIZE];
};

structure B{
   struct linked_list somelist;
};

struct A a;
unsigned long offset;
offset = (unsigned long)(&((struct B *)0)->somelist);//what is (struct B *)0??
hash = get_hash(some_string);//so this is hash code
tempnode = a.list[hash];
while (tempnode != NULL){
    entry = (struct B *)((unsigned long)tempnode - offset);//get every node?
    tempnode = tempnode->next;
}
```

Comment: IMHO you don't need `structure B` (it was probably intended as a dummy-head). BTW: you *do* need semicolons after struct definitions.

Comment: Please post code that will at least compile.

Comment: @joop  surely... right..

Comment: This is an illegal, but pretty common way of getting the byte offset of a field inside a struct.

Comment: Some programmers like to think that they can't trust the standard library. That they better write hacks that have undefined behavior, instead of using [`offsetof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/offsetof).

Comment: @Art Hi, so won't it have any risks? was the address for (struct B *)0)->somelist means the head?

Comment: I don't familar with the owner of this piece of code, but it did surprise me LOL @StoryTeller

Comment: @Michael - It `((struct B *)0)->` looks very much like dereferencing a  null pointer, which *is* high risk. Here it is also silly, as it tries to  compute the offset of the first member of a structure. I can tell you what *that* is - zero!

Comment: @BoPersson It won't always be zero. Consider the case that you add more fields later to the structure. Or even say a compiler implementation that adds padding before (struct memory layout is implementation defined). It is not *silly*.

Comment: @Art I am not sure if you can call this illegal. Taking address of fields of NULL structs had been an open issue for a long time. But AFAIK was closed as not an UB.

Comment: @BoPersson Also I don't see any dereference in `((struct B *)0)->`. A dereference occurs only when you convert the lvalue to a rvalue, which is clearly not happening here.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya When I followed a discussion to add `offsetof` to a kernel I was involved in the standards lawyer conclusion was "technically it's UB, but screw it, everyone else does the same thing". This was before gcc introduced `__builtin_offsetof`.

Comment: @Art, Oh! I was not aware of that.Off topic but could you point me to the discussion if possible? I would like to look at the arguments.

Comment: @MichaelPeng It has risks. It's unclear if this is undefined behavior, maybe it is, maybe it isn't, why risk it? Especially since there is a perfectly standard way of doing the exact same thing. The reason why I recognized the construct is because I know of many places that does the same thing, but those places have a very constrained environment that is only supported to be compiled by very particular compilers, so it was ok there.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I don't even remember where to look. It was in 2001. It's very likely this was discussed on an internal mailing list or even just irc.

Comment: @Art Nevermind, thanks!

Comment: @Art WOW, you are so amazing! Thanks!